# What's the Pythonic way to expose Cython attributes to Python?

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to make a Cython class that has some attributes that need to be accessible from Python. Right now, the cleanest way I can think of doing that is using `@property` to explicitly define getters and setters like so:

```
@property
def some_attr(self):
    return self._some_attr

@some_attr.setter
def some_attr(self, unicode val):
    self._some_attr = val
```

This feels like a lot of extraneous and verbose boiler plate to me. Is there no built-in way to just do this with a decorator in Cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword to define an attribute as accessible at Python level is `public`:

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef public unicode some_attr
    ...
```